# How to run shrink-window-horizontally multiple times, or how to repeat a function multiple times in general?

Tags: window, functions

I wanted to define a function to execute a command multiple times and ended up using `fset`:

```
(fset 'my-shrink (kbd "C-u 43 C-x {"))
```

Now, I want to include this in a function, like this:

```
(defun my-todo ()
  (interactive)
  (find-file "~/Dropbox/orgfiles/tasks.org")
  (split-window-right)
  (my-shrink)             ; this won't work
  )
```

but it failed with "Invalid function: my-shrink". Apparently, `my-shrink` is not a function, so I can I call it in a function? Or, alternatively, how to do something similar to my-shrink in a function? BTW, all `my-shrink` does it to run `shrink-window-horizontally` 43 times.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Since you've accepted an answer that doesn't at all say "how to execute an fset command in a function", please change your question and its title, to say that you're looking for how to shrink a window or whatever... The Q&A should be clear, so that it can help others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could define it this way:

```
(defun my-shrink ()
  (interactive)
  (dotimes (_ 43)
    (shrink-window-horizontally 1)))
```

But that's not quite as elegant as this:

```
(defun my-shrink ()
  (interactive)
  (shrink-window-horizontally 43))
```

And since that's so short, maybe you don't even need to define anything at all. Just call `(shrink-window-horizontally 43)` in `my-todo`.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize that shrink-window-horizontally takes arguments. Not I also learned a way to repeat any command multiple times in a function.

Comment: You can find that sort of information by using the `C-h f` command, then typing in a function name. It will show you the argument list and the documentation of the function, including links to the source code and the manual.

Comment: @db48x: Yes.  @Jordan: when I write emacs-lisp code, I use the minor mode `eldoc-mode`. When typing `(shrink-window-horizontally` followed by a space, the modeline shows the expected arguments.